# Getting time of Sysdate Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote this line to get the date and time together from int datatype to timestamp:

```
(to_timestamp(cast(theDate* 1000000 + theTime as varchar2(255)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MIss'))
```

I need to add it to where clause to get only where the date + the time is less then 5 hours of the

current date, to be more clear i need the query to show me only the date from the last 5 hours on the sysdate.

Something like this:

```
Where hour((to_timestamp(cast(theDate* 1000000 + theTime as varchar2(255)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MIss'))) - hour(sysdate) < 5
```

if i can use datediff on oracle i wil use this for example:

where datediff  ('HOUR', (imrecorddate, imrecordtime), sysdate ) < 5

I would like to get some help becasue i didnt find it on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.  What does this mean "show me only the date from the last 5 hours on the sysdate."

Comment: What is the reason for storing date and time seperately as integers? If you stored this as a datetime (called `DATE` in Oracle) directly, all these conversions`would not be necessary and writing your queries would be much, much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the last five hours, then just use date/time comparisons.  Assuming there are no future date/times:

```
where (to_timestamp(cast(theDate* 1000000 + theTime as varchar2(255)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MIss')) >= current_timestamp - interval '5' hour
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
but i got this error
01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
*Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
*Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.

Comment: @EfraimEfiGavrieli . . . This is using *exactly* the logic in your question, with ` >= current_timestamp - interval '5' hour` following it.  That second part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  thedate INT,
  thetime INT
);
```

*(This is bad practice and you should just use a single `DATE` column which would support the same date and time components.)*

and the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( thedate, thetime )
WITH dates ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '04:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '04:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '05:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '05:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_CHAR( dt, 'YYYYMMDD' ), TO_CHAR( dt, 'HH24MISS' ) FROM dates;
```

Then you can do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE( thedate||TO_CHAR(thetime, 'FM000000'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
         >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' HOUR;
```

Which would output:

> | THEDATE | THETIME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 20210604 | 90321 |
> | 20210604 | 90320 |
> | 20210604 | 90319 |

---

Now, if your table stores values in the UTC time zone and your system time is in a different time zone then you need to include the time zone:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         thedate||TO_CHAR(thetime, 'FM000000')||'+0000',
         'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZHTZM'
       ) >= SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' HOUR;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8a243c93731e4fab7aaa1212ec5842a)*